# On the Bash command-line, how do you cut the word immediately after the cursor?

Tags: bash, command-line

On the Bash command-line, how do you cut the word immediately after the cursor?

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> cuts the word before it.

Comment: [How to delete a whole word on the right in Linux Bash Shell command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53967223/how-to-delete-a-whole-word-on-the-right-in-linux-bash-shell-command-line) offers additional insight into this

Answer (score 9):

I usually do this using <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>. You can look up "readline Emacs shortcuts".

Comment: On macOS, Alt + D enters ∂.