# How to delete a whole word after the cursor in a Bash-like command-line tool?

Tags: bash, shell, shortcut, readline, key-bindings

In command-line applications as the [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) shell that implement [readline](/questions/tagged/readline)-like line editing capabilities, there is a key binding for deleting a whole word *before* the cursor, which is by default <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>.

**Is there a key binding for deleting a whole word *after* (to the right of) the cursor?** If not, how can I achieve this?

Comment: CTRL D = Delete character at the cursor

Comment: The [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12334750/6243352) should be closed as a dupe of this one rather than the other way around.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Use <kbd>Esc</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> to delete the word on the right.

Comment: This moves the word to the right of the cursor into a ring buffer. The last added element can be accessed via Ctrl+y. The possibly existing further elements in the ring buffer can then be called up via repeated Esc+y.

Comment: Only `Esc+D` works for me. Which is OK. But how do I change to or add `Alt+D`?

Comment: For Mac users, it's Ctrl^ + D

Answer (score 4):

You can try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> to delete from the cursor to end of the line (all on the left side of the cursor), and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> to delete from the cursor to the start of the line (all to the right side of the cursor).

Also, I find the nice blog post *[Bash Shortcuts For Maximum Productivity](https://skorks.com/2009/09/bash-shortcuts-for-maximum-productivity/)* covering a handful of Bash shortcut, and you may want to give it a read.

Comment: These two are already listed in the question itself, and the question is about deleting just a single word.